# Visual studio code command doesn't work on WSL 2

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason, when I type the command `code .` from a WSL terminal I have the message:

```
Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal.
```

After some research, I tried to fix it with the following commands:

- `rm -r ~/.vscode-server`
- `code .`

It redownloads VS Code Server and it works correctly but just for one terminal instance. When I open a new terminal, I still have the message :

```
Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal.
```

I don't have the issue when I use the command `code` in a VS code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [wslu](https://wslutiliti.es/wslu/install.html) just helped me & a colleague with Ubuntu 22.04 under windows 11 - in both a bash terminal within and outside of code.